# How to merge two excel sheets by patient ID without excluding duplicate data

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to merge two data sheets by patient ID including all data. Is there an easy way to combine two excel sheets and create one data file in excel. 
Sheet 1 is in the left side and sheet 2 is in the right side.

[image][image]

Comment: What would be your desired output. Can you do that manually and add that screenshot as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use Manthan Patel's Vlookup method if you create a unique ID on **both sheets**.  You can create a dummy ID by inserting a column to the left of your ID and then use

```
=B2 & "-" & countif($B$2:B2,B2)
```

in cell `A2` and then auto-fill down.  You will then have a unique ID for each row that you can use a vlookup on to get the data onto sheet2.  The ID will be 1-1, 1-2, 2-1,

The limitation will be if Sheet2 has less rows for a particular patient ID than Sheet1 so you need to also think about the output that you are trying to acheive when you merge the sheets.